# Send a custom form control validator a FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm very simply trying to validate a control if its value matches a value within a FormArray.

I want to be clear that **I do not want to validate the form or a FormGroup or a FormArray**. This question is for learning how to pass parameters to a validator function and the validation of the `addValue` control.

Here is what I have in my custom validation service:

```
public form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    addValue: this.fb.control(null, [this.validatorService.duplicate(this.form.get('values'))]),
    values: this.fb.array([])
});
```

And the validator function

```
public duplicate(values: FormArray): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        for (let i = 0, j = values.length; i < j; i++ ) {
            if (control.value === values[i].value) {
                return { 'duplicate': true };
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

At this point I get an error where I add the validator with the FormArray as an argument:

> Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'FormArray'.   Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'FormArray': controls, at, push, insert, and 5
>   more.ts(2345) (property) FormGroup.controls: {
>       [key: string]: AbstractControl; }

Can someone show me how to send a FormArray into a validator function?

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/send-validator-formarray?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvalidator.service.ts) of the validator NOT getting the  FormArray

Answer (score 3):

AbstractControl is the base class, simply cast you it:

```
public form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    addValue: this.fb.control(null, [this.validatorService.duplicate(this.form.get('values') as FormArray)]),
    values: this.fb.array([])
});
```

you could also sends values directly:

```
this.validatorService.duplicate(this.form ? this.form.get('values').value : []);
```

and

```
public duplicate(values: string[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        for (let i = 0, j = values.length; i < j; i++ ) {
            if (control.value === values[i]) {
                return { 'duplicate': true };
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

### NEW ANSWER

Instead add a form Validator:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  addValue: this.fb.control(null),
  values: this.fb.array(['test2', 'test3'])
}, { validator: this.validatorService.duplicate2 });
```

using this code:

```
public duplicate2(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const newValue = control.get('addValue') ? control.get('addValue').value : null;
    const values = control.get('values') ? control.get('values').value : [];

    console.log("1 " + newValue);
    console.log(values);
    for (let i = 0, j = values.length; i < j; i++ ) {
              if (newValue === values[i]) {
                  return { 'duplicate2': true };
              }
          }
          return null;          
  }
```

and also change your validation:

```
<app-validator [control]="form"></app-validator>
```

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/send-validator-formarray-l8j7ys

you can pass the field names as parameter to the validator.

Comment: Accessing `values` seems to be causing an undefined error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` I'm a bit stumped. I tried adding the `addValue` control later to see if that helped and got the original error from my question again.

Comment: The ternary method is causing `Argument of type 'undefined[] | FormArray' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormArray'.`

Comment: @TR3B As mentionned, I change  the validation function parameter to be an array... if you want to keep the formArray, send null or new FormArray (this.form ? this.form.get('values').value : null)

Comment: Yes that does not send the array to the validator https://stackblitz.com/edit/send-validator-formarray

Comment: @TR3B I Forked your stackblitz, see my update. But really I think you're not using FormArrays the right way (Insterad of AddValue, add an actual item to the array) anyway, good luck

Comment: Thanks @moi_meme for the ideas. However I'm not trying to validate a group or a form as mentioned in bold in my question.

Comment: @TR3B what's wrong with the stackblitz i linked, the function duplicate2 isn't doing what you require? It validates if newValue from addValue control exists in values from FormArray values...

Comment: Because you've used group validation. In the future I'd like to be able to add the `duplicate` validator to any control and send it any FormArray. Possibly even from another group or form. You have a good solution to group validation but it won't solve the question.

Comment: @TR3B as mentionned, you can change the methos to add the name of the FormArray as a parameter and use it to find the FormArray... otherwise, on a control it would only work on a static list, not a formArray.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to access to a FormArray, which is not instantiated yet:

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
  addValue: this.fb.control(null, [this.validatorService.duplicate(this.form ? this.form.get('values').value : []), Validators.minLength(2)]),
  values: this.fb.array([])
});
```

to solve this you have to options:

1) instantiate the FormArray first 
2) Add the validator after instantiating the FormGroup

Comment: Yes I tried that too. Adding the validator after we create the form does not work. You're welcome to try with the StackBlitz?